# Losing indices From KIBANA When I stop docker compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, filebeat

i have elasticsearch:7.17 and kibana:7.17 installed Using docker compose
indices are sent to elasticsearch Using filebeat

When i run This command on my terminal : docker-compose down

i lose all indices and index pattern That ive Created in kibana

Comment: are you using docker volume?

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that you are not using volumes?
In order to persist data, you need to tell docker to use a volume as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

You can add a volume to a compose file as seen in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose), or here in the [elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-file):

```
...
services:
  es01:
    volumes:
     - path_on_your_machine:path_in_container:read_write_access
...
```

Comment: yes i'm using volume but to load data into elasticsearch i'm using a job in gitlab that use a  dockerfile of filebeat in gitlab that take json file from gitlab and send them to elasticsearch in remote server using gitlab runner  is that's the reason why cuz i have  read that jobs temporary create container is that means that it dosent stock data in elasticsearch